# Table reload taking too much time to update the cells

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have tried all the methods like run in main thread etc....
But none of them are working..
My table have more than 500 rows which contains images audios and as well as text..
each time reload of table taking minimum of 5to10 seconds of time and ui is freezing.
Please help me out in this...

Comment: Please show some code so we can figure out where you did mistake.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.... more time taken in the  heightForRowAtIndexPath while calculating height for individual rows... when i reload table its taking more time for 500 rows height and are of different heights ...

Comment: Please,Post some code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**u can use NSOperational Queue:**

```
NSOperationQueue *que = [[NSOperationQueue alloc]init];

        [que addOperationWithBlock:^{

                [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{


       //u can assign all the table view values and content here

       // it will not pause the data u can scroll immediately             
            }];

        }];
```

**solution 2:**

call ur  data:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
//call ur data methods or web services methods in side this block 
    });
```

assign the data in a table view :

```
 NSOperationQueue *que = [[NSOperationQueue alloc]init];

            [que addOperationWithBlock:^{

                    [[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] addOperationWithBlock:^{


           //u can assign all the table view values and content here

           // it will not pause the data u can scroll immediately             
                }];

            }];
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.... more time taken in the heightForRowAtIndexPath while calculating height for individual rows... when i reload table its taking more time for 500 rows height and are of different heights ... Your method will work fine.. but the problem is it will take 3secs of time to update the table after height calculated

Comment: r u getting the data from server to fill the table or local memory

Comment: from local database/Memory m getting data

Comment: check now @BhaskarCm

Comment: is it working...  for me its worked perfect ... @BhaskarCm

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142150/discussion-between-naveen-kumar-and-bhaskar-cm).

Answer (score 0):

you need use GCD for this :

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0),
                   // do backgroud work
                   ^{
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            // do UI work like
            // label.text = ""
            // or many others
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @KKRocks answer, in most cases there is no need populate table with all 500 rows, you can populate only 50 and dynamically add cells when scrolling to bottom.

Answer (score 0):

Think you are using

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

datasource method for cell creation as well as data setting. My Suggestion is use data source methods only for cell creation.  Then use

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

delegate method for setting data. Use this sample code

```
  - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

{

```
MyWishListTableViewCell *cell = [tableView 
dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Order_Cell_Indntifire" 
forIndexPath:indexPath];
return cell;
}
```

}

```
    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

{

```
 if ([cell isKindOfClass:[MyWishListTableViewCell class]])
 {
MyWishListModel* data = [_myWishListArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
 MyWishListTableViewCell *cell1 = (MyWishListTableViewCell*)cell;
 [cell1 setUpData:data];
}
```

}